# MSSQL convert with datetime does not output Z timezone indicator

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

According to the [MSSQL documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928.aspx) when calling `convert` with style `127` (ISO8601 with time zone Z) the output should be expected to look like `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ`.

But executing the following SQL will will output the same value (without `Z`) regardless of style 126 or 127

```
SELECT convert(nvarchar(64), GetUtcDate(), 127), convert(nvarchar(64), GetUtcDate(), 126)
```

Am I reading the documentation wrong? The first column should end with Z indicating UTC timezone, shouldn't it? Using MSSQL 2012.

Comment: Well, `127` has footnote 6 attached which says: "Only supported when casting from character data to **datetime** or **smalldatetime**." which isn't the operation you're attempting.

Comment: And footnote 7 say: "The optional time zone indicator, Z, is used to make it easier to map XML datetime values that have time zone information to SQL Server datetime values that have no time zone" which means it's really there as a convenience for inserting data rather than as an output format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're on 2012, you can use [`FORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) instead:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GetUtcDate(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffzzz')
```

Which produced, a short time ago:

```
2014-05-13 08:23:29.093+01:00
```

(Or, you could use `'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH:mm:ss.fffzzz'` if you want the `T` separator instead of space)

Comment: There's also the option of using the [`datetimeoffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) data type in 2012, although I personally haven't had the opportunity to use it yet.